# visit meta and visit parent buttons have broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, se2.0

For some reason the 'visit meta' and 'visit parent' buttons now link to stack exchange. strange bug.

well funnily enough, after posting this they have changed images and now say stack exchange so perhaps it's not a bug but those buttons were quite useful.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59571/wrong-link-for-the-visit-the-meta-on-all-area51-site

Comment: If you're still seeing the old visit meta/parent button at the left end of the top banner, do a "hard" reload (shift+ctrl+R in some browsers) to replace the cached image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is now situated between "log out" and "about" on the right hand side.

[image]